# Get single information form PHP variable array (from API)

Tags: php

I've build a short php tool to get data from a device API the current result is like below, what I need and try to set up is to get the data in single variables (to store them in DB).
In the array are all events from one single day. What I tried to do is to get the sum of the [USAGE] events in a single variabel.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start] => 2020-05-04T06:14:54.000Z
            [end] => 2020-05-04T06:14:59.000Z
            [id] => event_someid
            [usage] => 0.2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [start] => 2020-05-04T06:15:17.000Z
            [end] => 2020-05-04T06:15:22.000Z
            [id] => event_smeotherid
            [usage] => 0.1
        )
...
)
```

**Part of the php code**

```
...
    $ch = curl_init();
    $id = $alldevices[0]->id;
    $start ="2020-05-04T00:00:01.000Z";
    $end = "2020-05-04T23:59:59.000Z";
    $unit = "l";
    $url = "https://apicallurl/".$id."/events?start=".$start."&end=".$end."&unit=".$unit."";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    $headers[] = "x-access-token: ".$token."";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $Usagedata = json_decode(curl_exec($ch))->events;
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);


    print "<pre>";
    print_r($Usagedata);
    print "</pre>";
```

So finally the API and call works fine, but I don't get it to start this script with the pre-defined time-frame and only get the sum of all usage events in a single variable.

Thanks a lot!
Best,

Comment: Do you have any problem regarding Curl, APIs or JSON? The idea I grasp from your question is that you're actually asking how to sum numbers from an array :-?

Comment: `array_sum(array_map(function($i) {return $i->usage;},$Usagedata));`

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález - the script and curl is working, sometimes you hang on a single command.. ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Thanks! Exact what I tried to do. Solved.